# Unable to create Java Virtual Machine Error while running Sonar analysis

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

### Version Used

SonarQube 7.3 integrated with TC using SonarScanner using version `sonar-scanner-msbuild.4.0.2.892`

### Error received

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.*
>   Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx14336m*
>   The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.*
>   Process returned exit code 1*
>   The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully*
>   Creating a summary markdown file…*
>   Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1*
>   Process exited with code 1*

### Steps Taken

I tried various values of `Xmx` and elastic search `Xmx` values to get over the error ranging from 7000M to 10000M, but the MSbuild step which is in between the begin and end analysis steps runs for almost 6 hrs and fails at the end analysis step. Just to add into perspective I am scanning over 10M Loc

Comment: Try adding "-XX:-UseCompressedOops ". UseCompressedOops limits max heap to around 16GB.

Comment: Two silly questions. 1. How much RAM does you server have? 2. Which Java is used to execute scans (`java -version`)?

Comment: I am running my macine on 16GB RAM and using the latest java (java version "1.8.0_181")